# Powershell for IIS

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have two different text file having different harder for example as below

Example1.txt having header WebAppName, Version,state,UserIdentityType,Username,Password

Example2.txt having Name,state,application

So I need to concatenating both output into signal text file on Example1.txt using powershell.

Anyone provide solution also I try 
GC Example1.txt, Example2.txt | add-content Example1.txt 
But I don't get results as expected due to different harder.

[image: Get_IIS_Webapplucation.ps1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want to concatenate the two files you can simply get their contents and loop over all the lines and concatenate them into a new line:

```
$example1 = Get-Content .Example1.ps1;
$example2 = Get-Content .\Example2.ps1

$output = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new();

for($c = 0; $c -lt $example1.Count; $c++) 
{ 
    $null = $output.Append($example1[$c]); 
    $null = $output.Append(','); 
    $null = $output.AppendLine($example2[$c]); 
}

$sb.ToString() | Out-File .\Output.txt
```

You certainly have to make sure, that both files have the same number of lines.

Comment: Thank you @Ronald !